# Solved problem on radioactive decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity

[image][image]I encountered a question that was given the disintegration rate of a radio active source measured at the interval of four minute. The source is consisted of two types of radio nucleus and the half lives of both the nucleus has to be calculated. 
http://www.academia.edu/34857733/Solved_problems_in_modern_physics
The problem solution is on the 417 page on the given link. .
I really dont understand how they came up with the graph and the formula seems very convoluted to me. Im inserting pictures of the pages for convenience.

Anybody please explain i would be grateful.

Comment: Are we asked to download 417 pages?

Comment: i have inserted the pictures for your convenience .Im new in here dont know how to put up with

Comment: This was better when the two images were visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single radioactive source,

$$N(t) = N_{0} \exp(-\lambda t) $$

Differentiating w.r.t. time and taking the positive value, the activity is

$$ A(t) = \lambda N_{0} \exp(-\lambda t) $$

take natural logarithms on both sides,

$$\log A(t) = \log \lambda N_{0} -  \lambda t $$

Plotting activity against time for a single source gives you a straight line of gradient

$ -\lambda = -\frac{\log 2}{t_{\frac{1}{2}}}$ where $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the half life.

Towards the end, the shorter-lived substance nearly dies out. So activity is almost solely due to the longer-lived substance and the graph is a straight line. Find the slope of this line to find the activity of the longer-lived substance.

To find the activity of the short-lived substance, extrapolate the line you just found to $t = 0$ and subtract the activity of the long-lived substance from the total activity at smaller times and use this to find the halflife of the short-lived substance.

Comment: Can u kindly explain the subtraction part  more in details

Comment: When you extrapolate the line to small $t$, you get the values for $\log A(t)$ for the long lived sample. From this you can find $A(t)$ for the long lived sample. Subtract this from the total activity to get the activity for the short lived sample at different times. From here, you get the half life for the short lived sample.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is a plot of the data in the second row of the table. The text explains how the lines were drawn.

Comment: can u explain the formula sir